# ImGui unputText в цикле

Tags: c++, imgui

Код создает поле ввода по кнопке, но вводить текст можно только в последний созданный, а так же текст введённый в последнее поле ввода отображается везде. Как исправить? За помощь - заранее спасибо!

```
int j = 1;
std::vector<float> my_var;
char buf[256];
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
                    {
                        ImGui::Text(u8"'Поле ввода: вопрос'");
                        if(ImGui::InputText("##Test", buf, IM_ARRAYSIZE(buf)))
                        {
                            std::string s(buf);
                            my_var.push_back(std::stod(s));
                        }
                        
                        ImGui::Text(u8"'Поле ввода: правильный ответ'");
                        ImGui::Text(u8"'Поле ввода: 'Кол-во баллов за правильный ответ'");
                        ImGui::Separator();
                    }
                    if (ImGui::Button(u8"Добавить вопрос"))
                    {
                        j++;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У разных виджетов должны быть разные имена. Используйте, например, `ImGui::InputText(("##Test" + std::to_string(i)).c_str(), ...);`.

Или, другой вариант, оберните тело цикла в `ImGui::PushID(i); ... ImGui::PopID();`, эффект будет похожий.

---

Непонятно, зачем вам `ImGui::InputText`, работающий с массивом байт. Есть `ImGui::InputFloat`, который читает сразу число.

Но даже если бы вам была нужна строка, а не число, то лучше использовать другую перегрузку `ImGui::InputText` из `<misc/cpp/imgui_stdlib.h>`, которая сразу работает с `std::string *`.

---

Также, `push_back` в теле `if` выглядит сомнительно. Разве он не срабатывает на каждое изменение отдельного символа? Лучше сделать отдельную кнопку, завершающую ввод числа, или передавать `ImGuiInputTextFlags_EnterReturnsTrue`, чтобы `if` срабатывал только при нажатии Enter.

Comment: Вылезает ошибка:
`_NODISCARD size_type capacity() const noexcept 
{
return _Mypair._Myval2._Myres;
}`

Comment: @Quarkss Покажите ваш код, и полный текст ошибки дословно.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/n94zbwQ
`
std::string* bb;
int j = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
     { 
      ImGui::InputText2(("##Test" + std::to_string(i)).c_str(), bb, IM_ARRAYSIZE(bb));
     }
     if (ImGui::Button(u8"Добавить вопрос"))
     {
      j++;
     }`

Comment: @Quarkss Что за `InputText2`? Последний аргумент лишний, уберите. Второй аргумент неправильный - создайте просто строку, а не указатель, и добавляйте `&` при передаче. Убедитесь, что создаете строку один раз, а не заново каждый кадр.

Comment: InputText2 - это InputText из <misc/cpp/imgui_stdlib.h>
Сделал как вы сказали, вылетать перестало, писать можно в каждой строке, но текст пишется во все. 
https://imgur.com/a/9xPZAXv

Comment: @Quarkss Ну дык надо разные строки в разные поля передавать. Сделайте массив... А про `InputText2` - откуда двойка в имени? Вы в коде имгуи ее написали, или скопипастили себе функцию с другим именем? И то и другое - лишнее, должно работать и с одинаковым названием.